# how to delete and update a single image from array of images store in a single column of database using php mysqli?

Tags: php, image

```
<?php //display.php//
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ist_softtech");
 $i="";
$query="select * from single_field_tbl";
$fire=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($fire);
$res=$data['imagess'];
$rest=explode(" ",$res);
$count=count($rest)-1;
for($i=0;$i<$count;++$i)
{
    ?>
    <img src="uploads/<?= $rest[$i]?>" height="200px" width="200px"/>
    <?php
}
       echo "<p style='color:green;font-size:26px'>Total ".$count." images found.";


?>
```

i want to add and update database having multiple images in a single column.
i want to add and update database having multiple images in a single column

Answer (score 0):

$res=$data['imagess'];
Are you sure its imagess not images here?

$rest=explode(" ",$res);
Some of the file name includes spaces in it so using space to explode is not a good idea. You can use some specific set of characters like:
$rest=explode("|||",$res); to divide the filenames.

But why would you have multiple images in a single database column. As far as I have understood, you wanted to have multiple images for a single parameter. Try having two database tables: one for all details and other for images only. For example:

Table 1:
id title description

Table 2:
id category-id filename

Here category-id is the id to table 1 used as foreign key.